# Adding list in list

Tags: c#, .net, list, exception, nullreferenceexception

I have class SellStatement

```
public class SellStatement
{
    public long billNo
    public DateTime paymentDate;
    public List<string>  ProductName;
    public List<double> quantity;
    public List<double> ratePerQuantity;
}
```

When i am trying to access function GetSaleDetails

```
public Exception GetSaleDetails(List<SellStatement> lss1,string query)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lss1.ToArray().Length; i++)
            {
                query = "select * from [product details] where [bill no]=@billno";
                com = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billno",lss1[i].billNo);
                sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    lss1[i].ProductName.Add(sdr.GetString(1));//Exception line
                    lss1[i].quantity.Add(sdr.GetDouble(2));
                    lss1[i].ratePerQuantity.Add(sdr.GetDouble(3));       
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            con.Close();
            return e;
        }
    }
```

Null Reference Exception comes up at`lss1[i].ProductName.Add(sdr.GetString(1));`.I think error might be because of null value in at `sdr.GetString(1)` but i checked it has some value .My friend told me that you can't change Function argument value like this so i try to copy one list to other like this .

```
 List<SellStatement> lss1 = new List<SellStatement>() ;
            lss1.AddRange(lss);
```

But it doesn't help me out. I am not able to figure out what's wrong while adding element.

Comment: You need to learn how to handle exceptions...

Comment: please tell me What is wrong in this code .

Comment: First of all, you don't `return` an Exception... You `throw` them. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.110).aspx).Secondly, have you checked if your queries return valid values? You are not checking on anything. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: bash.d this function is only for test and yes i checked my query values before executing this it return valid values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you showed us your complete `SellStatement` class in the question, then the reason is clear:
You never initialized `ProductName`, `quantity` and `ratePerQuantity`. They are `null` and that's exactly what the exception is telling you.

To fix it, change your class to this:

```
public class SellStatement
{
    public long billNo
    public DateTime paymentDate;
    public List<string> ProductName = new List<string>();
    public List<double> quantity = new List<double>();
    public List<double> ratePerQuantity = new List<double>();
}
```

Please note that this goes against the normal C# design guidelines that say you shouldn't have public fields. Consider redesigning your class like so:

```
public class SellStatement
{
    List<string> _productName = new List<string>();
    List<double> _quantity = new List<double>();
    List<double> _ratePerQuantity = new List<double>();

    public long billNo {get; set;}
    public DateTime paymentDate  {get; set;}
    public List<string> ProductName { get { return _productName; } }
    public List<double> quantity { get { return _quantity; } }
    public List<double> ratePerQuantity { get { return _ratePerQuantity; } }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what my function needs Daniel you are true expert thank you very much and i am very sorry for such a foolish mistake .

Comment: @DGibbs: Why? `lss1` is a list of `SellStatement` objects. This very well can be non-null and the place of his exception confirms this. The problem was that each of the `SellStatement` instances had members that were `null`. Have a close look at the line that throws the exception: `lss1[i].ProductName.Add(sdr.GetString(1));`: It calls `Add` on `ProductName` which is `null`. The NRE didn't occur because `lss1` or `lss1[i]` were `null`.